# Sustituir varias strings en PHP

Tags: php, array

Quiero mediante PHP sustituir el resultado de varias variables, cada variable tiene un valor diferente, me gustaría que si un valor me da un resultado sea cambiado por otro.

```
$descarga1 > Esto me devuelve el valor > Mega.co.nz ó Dropbox.com
$descarga2 > Esto me devuelve el valor > Mediafire.com ó libros.relaxmind.info
$descarga3 > Esto me devuelve el valor > Googledrive.com o Box.net
```

Para remplazar estoy intentando hacerlo de este modo:

```
function str_replace($descarga1,$descarga2,$descarga3){

str_replace(
    array("Mega.co.nz","Obtén el libro desde Mega.nz"),
    array("Dropbox.com", "Obtén el libro desde Dropbox.com"),
    array("Mediafire.com","Obtén el libro desde Mediafire.com"),
    array("libros.relaxmind.info", "Obtén el libro desde nuestra web"),
    array("Googledrive.com","Obtén el libro desde Google Drive"),
    array("Box.net", "Obtén el libro desde Box.net"),
);
return $
```

Hasta aquí me he atorado, Espero haberme dado a entender de la forma correcta, En resumen me gustaría que si `$descarga1, $descarga2 o $descarga3`alojan un resultado, este sea cambiado por Obtén el libro `desde nombre del servidor`.

Espero puedan ayudarme, Gracias!.

Comment: Deberias especificar un poco mas lo que necesitas, no se entiende muy bien la pregunta

Comment: Una disculpa, he editado mi pregunta. Espero que pueda ser mejor entendida.

Comment: Solo has cambiado la puntuacion, no necesariamente la hace mas entendible

Comment: Aunque si quieres, podrias darte una pasada por el chat y de podre ayudar

Comment: Voy al Chat entonces, Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Perfecto, conversemos en el chat

Comment: @JosephYang y si reemplazas cadena por cadena , si es que pasas los tres tu tipo de retorno sería un `Array` sería "mejor" si a la función se le pasa el `String` a reemplazar y el `array`

Comment: @Dev.Joel use esta forma: $descarga1 = str_replace(array("mega.nz","dropbox.com"), array("Obtén el libro desde Mega.nz", "Obtén el Libro desde Dropbox.com"), $descarga1); Hago lo mismo para $descarga2 y $descarga3, me gustaría hacerlo de una forma mas limpia o mas organizada.

Comment: @JosephYang revisar mi respuesta a ver si es lo que busca. igual no está muy clara su pregunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Propondré una forma un poco más "limpia" ,  quizá su función deba recibir la lista y el elemento a modificar. *teniendo en cuenta la idea que si quiere cambiar 10 valores, ¿ enviará 10 parámetros?*  , la función tendría la siguiente forma , donde emplearemos la función [strtr](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strtr.php) que acepta como parámetro un `array` de tipo `clave => valor`.

```
function replaceAll($value,$list){
  return strtr($value, $list);
}
```

Para utilizar esta función , debe crear la lista de opciones_completamente adaptable a las opciones que pueda tener_ y pasar la palabra  a reemplazar.

```
$list = array("Mega.co.nz"=>"Obtén el libro desde Mega.nz",
           "Dropbox.com"=> "Obtén el libro desde Dropbox.com",
           "Mediafire.com"=>"Obtén el libro desde Mediafire.com",
           "libros.relaxmind.info"=> "Obtén el libro desde nuestra web",
           "Googledrive.com"=>"Obtén el libro desde Google Drive",
           "Box.net" => "Obtén el libro desde Box.net");

$descarga1 = "Box.net";
echo replaceAll($descarga1,$list);
$descarga2 = "libros.relaxmind.info";
echo replaceAll($descarga2,$list);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Es justo lo que estaba buscando, Agradezco el haberse tomado su tiempo y haberme orientado. Saludos!